# Technician kills an early time traveller, requests private trial

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Another question reminded me of this short story, which I read in an anthology before 2000.

- A time machine has been constructed. It takes up a lot of space, possibly the entire ground floor of a building, and uses a lot of power to project a small payload back in time.
- One man had gone back, and while he was away, a technician cut the power.
- Cutting the power meant certain death for the traveller.
- The person who switched it off is to be tried for murder but requests a private trial, I think with no jury.

> The man who went back had taken a modern gun and intended to prevent the crucifixion of Jesus Christ. The technician was unsure whether he'd succeed, but was unwilling to risk it.

> The private trial was because the technician believed most people would side with the time traveller, but a well-educated judge would understand that preventing the atonement and/or creating a huge paradox was a bad idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The Rescuer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55484) by Arthur Porges.

As you say, the time machine is huge:

> It was by far the largest, most intricate machine ever built. Its great complex of auxiliary components covered two square blocks, and extended hundreds of feet beneath the earth. There were fifty huge electronic computers at the heart of it. They had to be capable of solving up to thirty thousand simultaneous partial differential equations in as many variables in any particular millisecond. The energy which the machine required to operate successfully on a mass of M pounds was given by a familiar formula:
> E = MK²
> The K was not, as in Einstein’s equation, the velocity of light; but it was large enough so that only one type of power could be used: the thermonuclear reaction called hydrogen fusion.

But it is destroyed by two men, Dr. Carnot and Dr. Kent, not one man:

> It was the largest, most intricate, expensive, fascinating, and dangerous machine ever built. And two men were about to destroy it. They would have to release a large amount of thermonuclear energy in order to wreck the machine. It was the only way in the circumstances. It was a heartbreaking decision to have to make. Perhaps they should have contacted higher authorities in Washington, since the machine, although quite international in scope, was located in California; but that was too dangerous with time so short. Bureaucratic timidity might very well cause a fatal delay. So, knowing the consequences to them, the two scientists did what they believed had to be done. The machine, together with several blocks of supporting equipment, including the irreplaceable computers, was vaporized. They escaped in a fast air car.

The story is written as a conversation between Dr. Carnot and the Judge, and it ends:

> DR CARNOT: You still don’t know the real danger. What I’ve said so far applies to an impulsive, random trip to the distant past, where the man had no specific intentions. But Michael Nauss did have a particular plan - a wild, crazy, and yet, in a way, magnificent conception. One that the public, or much of it, might foolishly support without realizing the consequences. I speak of this country, and people in Europe; not in Asia, for the most part. And he had set the vernier with perfect precision, which made his plan even more feasible.
>
> JUDGE CLARK: What was he going to do?
>
> DR CARNOT: According to his note, this man had taken with him a repeating rifle and five thousand rounds of exploding ammunition. His intention was nothing less than to arrive at Golgotha in time to rescue Jesus Christ from the Roman soldiers. In short, to prevent the crucifixion. And with a modern rifle, who can say he wouldn’t succeed? And then what? Then what? The implications are staggering. Disregarding the Christian dogma, which asserts Jesus had to die for our sins, what of the effect on the future, the entire stream of history, secular as well as religious? Maybe Jesus himself would have prevented this madman from saving him - but who can be sure? Yet, if you ask the man in the street, now, in this year 2015: Shall we save Jesus Christ from the cross? - what would he answer? Whose side would he take? Ours, or Michael Nauss’? That is why Dr Kent and I destroyed the machine; and why we face this court now. We believe the proceedings should not be released. The decision is yours. We made ours that night.

Comment: Spot on, and quick work - Thanks! Now that I have the name I can see it's been asked about before.